# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm setting the textview count to `VISIBLE` on the notfication
that consist of a textview, but I'm getting the error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

> MainActivity

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ids.add(childSnapshot.getKey());
            }


            int i;
            for ( i = 0 ; i < ids.size();i++)
            {
                ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Items").child(ids.get(i));

                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            hashmap.put(childSnapshot.getKey(),childSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        }


                        if(Integer.parseInt(hashmap.get("qty"))<=25)
                        {
                            badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });


            }
```

> On Create Options Menu

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.actionbar,menu);
         View notificaitons = menu.findItem(R.id.notification).getActionView();
        ImageButton iconButtonMessages = (ImageButton) notificaitons.findViewById(R.id.badge_icon_button);
        badge = (TextView) notificaitons.findViewById(R.id.noti);
        iconButtonMessages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Notification.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

> onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.notification:
            Intent intentHome = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
            startActivity(intentHome);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please

Comment: check this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16320675)

Comment: Where in your code are you adding the ValueEventListener? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

> reference.addValueEventListener(...)

When do you run this code?

My assumption that you receive callback to ValueEventListener listener before you initialise `badge` object